# How do I Rotate a Sprite in 2d Java

Tags: java, game-engine

I'm making a wizard game where I load sprites from a sprite sheet.  I use a pixel array to display the sprites.

Here is my sprite.java https://github.com/thefoothing/Java-2d_game/blob/master/Sprite.java

Here is my game.java https://github.com/thefoothing/Java-2d_game/blob/master/Game.java

How do I get my sprites to rotate?

Comment: Rotate how? When? Have you tried anything? Please trim down your code to a small runnable example that we can try to help you with.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a pixel array to render your game.. it is not worth it. There is no performance boost. You use all cpu power to render images not to mention changing pixel data manually is very cpu intensive. Using simple draw calls with compatible images gives your gpu some of the load and gives you more control over individual sprites and what not.

Trust me, pixel rendering being better/faster is a myth. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
AffineTransform reset = new AffineTransform();
reset.rotate(0,0,0);
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics)g;
g2.rotate(angle, x, y);
//draw image here
g2.setTransform(reset);
```

Graphics2D also has the ability to do everything else you are doing with basic Graphics class

Comment: I'm trying to rotate it when i fire it so I the arrow isn't fired sideways so in Andrews answer what do i set (graphics)g as because I get an error do i set it to my main render method graphics or something else.

Comment: Sorry that was actually a little typo. The line should be Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g; not (Graphics)g;

Comment: I just realized I can't do that because I'm rendering everything to one buffered image so if i do that it rotates the whole game how do you rotate individual sprites that are being rendered on to the buffered image?

Comment: Noticing now that you are rendering all your sprites by drawing a pixel array then you will need to find your own algorithm to position the pixels in the array based on the rotation.